# How to use V4L or V4L2 (Video for Linux) in Android?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, v4l2, v4l

Does Android Linux Kernel support V4L or V4L2 (Video for Linux). If not, is it possible to add it?

Comment: It depends from tablet to tablet. If you take Acer Iconia tablet, it is present. And most of the tabs have the support. This is included to add UVC support for cameras(one of the purposes). Even if not included, you can compile the linux kernel by enabling the V4L2 inside drivers. But it would be a problem to test it if you dont have a development platform in hand.

Answer (score 13):

Yes,Android support V4L2,Android camera subsystem internally uses V4L2.
For more reference pls check http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.porting/12285

Answer (score 1):

On newer devices it's actually used ( Samsung Note 3 or S4 GT-I9506 ) to play videos, handle the camera and so on.

Comment: Can you post a reference?